# Windows Server - Route any request via a set IP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, route

We have a Windows 2008 server that has multiple IP address' on it. When the server makes requests to other machines (Via a .Net Web App) we've found that the IP it's 'calling out' on is un-predictable which makes things difficult in terms of firewalls on the other servers.

It's been suggested that we can use ROUTE ADD to restrict outgoing connections to a certain domain name to always use a single IP.

Any ideas how we go about this?

Comment: open cmd and type `route add /?` the example it gives is actually very good for what you want todo

Comment: The **route** command isn't domain aware. It's only for the host routing table (IP). This does seem to be an issue with the host routing table.

Comment: No it isn't domain aware but if the IP of that domain doesn't change you can use that ip instead

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. So if I assume its a fixed IP - can anyone share an example on how we do that?